# iOS App Documents directory being dropped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdocumentdirectory

In my iOS app I am saving data in the documents directory, and it is all being flagged to NOT sync to the cloud as Apple suggests.

The issue I am having is every once in a while my app's documents directory is being deleted, which results in a loss of the user's data. I am having trouble finding when this happens, as it is rare and there is no one thing that is causing the issue.

I initially assumed the folder grew too large, so the OS just dropped the folder, but Apple does not state any size limit or anything for the documents directory, at least not that I could find.

Has anyone had a similar issue or does anyone have any info that should shed some light on my issue?

Thanks

EDIT:

The issue has just come up again, and here is a screenshot of my apps documents with no documents directory, it was just deleted:

[image]

Xcode also keeps spitting out this message after it happened every few seconds:

> Error: Failed end transaction from database 'cannot commit - no
>   transaction is active'

Comment: Note that the new Apple documentation says that files/directories flagged as "do not sync" may be deleted without warning/notice under some (supposedly extreme) circumstances.

Comment: I have same bug reports from users of 2 different apps. Do you find some workaround to avoid dropping?

Comment: @pilot34 I believe the reason it was happening was because when I worked on this app, I did not use Core Data. The app store a bunch of files in the documents directory that could have been more efficiently stored in a Core Data model.

Comment: Thx. I store gigabytes of m4a, mp4 and pdf files. I don't think saving them to CoreData is a good idea :(

Comment: @pilot34 Well to connect some dots the app was storing lots of mp3s.

Comment: @HotLicks could you provide a link to that documentation? I am encountering a problem with this in an app that I maintain and was starting to suspect that Apple was deleting files that were flagged for exclusion from backups, but I haven't been able to find any documentation to support this theory.

Comment: @ianthetechie - I believe you will find it somewhere in here: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html, but they rewrite that at regular intervals.  There once was a different, more technical page, but I can't find it offhand.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for the link. It looks like the current rewrite has removed that language, but sounds oddly conflicted :) It says to use the flag on files "that can be recreated but [need] to persist", which implies that they can be deleted. However, later on it says "These files will not be purged." The technical document (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) doesn't mention anything about the flag affecting persistence, but I still suspect that it does. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: Anything new on this issue? We have just hit this very same situation, where the system deletes hundreds of megabytes of data from the `Documents` folder with the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` flag. Some of our users where in AirPlane mode when this happened so there was no way for them to re-download the data.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have anything new on this sorry. I do not work on this project anymore.

Comment: @shelll Hi recently some of our users are facing the same problem. The Documents folder altogether seems to be deleted. Similar to your case, we also store some large data in the folder. Did you have any luck getting to the root of this ? or maybe a workaround to avoid this deletion ?

Comment: @user3752049 If I remember correctly, there was no 100% solution, because Apple can do anything. In our case the Documents folder's content, flagged for not syncing into iCoud, was deleted when the device had almost full internal storage e.g. just a few MiB of free space. We had even a case where we where downloading several files from our server and when the last file download was finished the first few files where already gone. Since then we tried to ensure that devices have at least 10% of free storage.

Comment: @shelll Thanks for your response. This behavior is disappointing. What is the point of having a key like NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey if it is not reliable. Looks like I will have to find an alternate implementation.

Comment: you guys can always try out iCloud containers as they don't get deleted

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's the document directory? Please check that. This is a known situation with Caches and tmp directories as reported [here](http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning).

Comment: Yes I am sure we are using the documents directory and I understand the functionally of the tmp and Caches directories. When it happened, I looked at my Applicaion data in Organizer and it contained the tmp and Caches directories but Documents was gone until I generated a file again, then it re-appeared with only the new file.

Comment: Then you are somehow deleting your files. Have you searched for all your NSFileManager calls? Try subclassing it and using asserts to check if it's deleting anything. Anyway, +1 for the mystery.

Comment: I logged everywhere I am deleting any files, but none of those calls should delete the whole directory itself, but its worth a try. The hardest thing is trying to re-create it as I stated it is not consistent.

Comment: I have not really looked into the issue as it has not happened in awhile, but it just did and I was able to get some more info on it, I edited my original post.